# Fabric/Fastlane - Automatically Add Device UDIDs

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, twitter-fabric, fastlane

I'm using Fabric and Fastlane to deploy my beta builds to testers. Currently, when I have a new tester, I invite them via email, and they go through the Fabric onboarding process. Then, on all future builds, they'll receive a message "*The developer needs to add the device's UDID to a build.*" So then I go to developer.apple.com and add their UDID to my provisioning profile, and they can run the next build. It works as desired.

Is there any way within Fabric/Fastlane to automate this process of adding UDIDs to the provisioning profile on deployment? It seems `sigh` within Fastlane can manage provisioning profiles, and Fabric obviously has access to the device UDIDs, but I can't find any documentation about this particular step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs on how you can use fastlane to automatically add device testers to your profile: https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/#best-practices

There is currently no automatic integration with Fabric Beta, you'll have to manually add it to your list of devices. It's definitely something that can be improved.

Comment: That documentation helps, thank you! I'd certainly love this integration if it ever pops up on Fastlane's todo's.